# Pushing variables onto an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I am trying to push data at the end of  the student tags array which is in an object, I was wondering how I could do this?

```
var tags = "2019 Student"


{
  "first_name": "Thomas",
  "last_name": "Lee",
  "student_tags": 
    ["2020 Student"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `push()` to add item to an Array.

```js
let tags = "2019 Student"


let obj = {
  "first_name": "Thomas",
  "last_name": "Lee",
  "student_tags": ["2020 Student"]
};

obj.student_tags.push(tags);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` on `student_tags`:

```
obj.student_tags.push(tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tags = "2019 Student"

var student = {
  "first_name": "Thomas",
  "last_name": "Lee",
  "email": "test@email.tel",
  "student_tags": 
    ["2020 Student"]
}
```

You can just go to the student_tags property and push the tag.

```
student.student_tags.push(tags);
```